# IIS Friendly URL configuration

Tags: asp.net, .htaccess, iis

I´m a noob with .NET and IIS, so, I have a system that need to handle friendly url´s and I would like to know the best strategy to proceed. So, I ask you:

I need to do the follow rule:

from: www.test.com.br/test/9/testing
to: www.test.com.br/testing

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

easier form:
URL Rewrite -> Add Rules -> Rule witch rewrite map ->
      Choose the rule action: Redirect
      Choose the rewrite map: "/testing"
      ok
 after: Add Mapping Entry...
     Original value: "/testing"
     New value: "/test/9/testing"
OK :)

Answer (score 0):

You could start from here http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module.

Regards